# Manjaro reset(delete) after reboot [VIRTUAL BOX]

Tags: virtualbox, archlinux

I installed manjaro on a Virtual box.
Otherwise, every file I created, custom I did is reset(delete) after a shutdown/reboot.
Can I find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are booting up a live cd build on your vbox. Are you sure you installed it on your vhd?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's okay.
I'm just too stupid, It was installed on my VM otherwise instead of click on 
"boot from the hard disk" I clicked on "Start Manjaro Linux"